# Column not found: 1054 Unknown column '0' in 'field list' laravel

Tags: php, mysql, excel, laravel

I Have problem when i insert data to database with excel format, i use maatwebsite/excel package.

**UndanganController@store**

```
if ($request->hasFile('alamatExcel')) {
    //Jika pakai kurir
    $file = $request->file('alamatExcel')->getRealPath();
    \Excel::load($file, function($render) {
        $aa = AlamatPenerima::insert($render->toArray());
        //dd($render->toArray());
    });
}
```

**AlamatPenerima.php**

```
<?php
namespace App;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class AlamatPenerima extends Model
{
    protected $table    = 'alamat_penerima';
    protected $fillable = ['nama_penerima', 'alamat_penerima', 'telepon', 'provinsi', 'kota_kabupaten'];
}
```

when i click submit button, it has error

> Column not found: 1054 Unknown column '0' in 'field list'
>
> dd($render->to Array)

[image: array dd]

i hope you can help me

Answer (score 0):

You have to get one level deeper in your array. As you can see in your example output you have an array with two dimensions `array[0][0]`, where the first one is the sheet and the second one are rows of the sheet.

To get the first sheet try this (mind the `first()` ):

```
\Excel::load($file, function($render) {
    $aa = AlamatPenerima::insert($render->first()->toArray());
});
```

P.S.: It should be `$reader`; not `$render`.